# Water tank burner goes out after moving temperature dial from lowest settings to "Low" indicator

Tags: water-heater, pilot-light

My water tank is a:
[image]

I've already replaced the thermocouple, but the problem occurs after I get the pilot light started and release the red push button

[image]

I move the upper dial to the on position from the pilot position.
Then I start turning the temperature dial clockwise. The burner lights, then quickly goes out.
This video shows the process from the point of letting go of the red push button:
https://imgur.com/R7v6tLw

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the lighting instructions precisely, particularly this part of step 8:

"... Continue to hold the 'red button' in for about one (1) minute after the pilot is lit.  Release button and it will pop back up.  Pilot should remain lit.  If it goes out, repeat steps 2 through 8."

I would make sure to do this, and test to see if the pilot light stays lit without adjusting the temperature yet.

I'm also unsure if your temperature dial is too far to the low side - it's gone beyond the little index marks on the knob.  In the manual, the lowest mark is the lowest temperature setting, so not sure why your knob goes past there.  edit: now looking at the manual and comparing your knob, your knob has less index marks, so perhaps this is fine.

The manual also says (page 18):

- The gas control (thermostat) is constructed with a built in safety shut-off device designed to shut off the gas supply to the burner if the pilot flame is extinguished for any reason.
- The gas control (thermostat) is also equipped with a single use gas shut off device that will shut off the gas supply to the burner if the water heater exceeds normal operating temperatures.

In your video, when you turn the gas on, it looks like it's coming on pretty rapidly - this could be due to turning the knob too fast or something funny with the markings like I mentioned above.  This excess gas pressure could be blowing out the pilot light and causing the thermostat to shut off the gas supply to the burner.